# How would I encode RSA private key, given that I know the decimal representation of all of its components?

Tags: rsa, public-key

('n', '0x8978ee9e52ad5dee313b1401bc04d04fa3f90ca7018fc256afc67fc200390cbbL')

('p', '0xd098978cde12b9e101b519d42ca54e7dL')

('q', '0xa8b69b77f593ca8a280dcd7d757d9597L')

('e', '0x10001')

('d', '0x17e6c54214a8dcdc7585ca8834aaf796a797496607aa7660153859d02ba399a5L')

('dp', '0x7978a2a8319a0e0c6d861ca865e74db1L')

('dq', '0x38f797dd5495b7b118bf3860a1786b37L')

('qinv', '0x5116fa4d2efd8072ba7fe9e94831413fL')

How would I create a base 64 encoded RSA private key?

Comment: I’d suggest you don’t use that private key for anything serious, now you have published it. Anyway, all of it depends how you need to have that key encoded…

Comment: Actually, it's a 256 bit RSA key; whether or not it is published, I hope you wouldn't use that for anything serious...

Comment: I can easily do this in Java as well, usually these development related questions are better asked at StackOverflow, where you can indicate your favorite runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a Python module called [pycrypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto) that makes it easy to construct RSA keys from arbitrary values (using the [`construct()` method](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.RSAImplementation-class.html#construct)).

The following code (Python 2.7) should do the job:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
n = 0x8978ee9e52ad5dee313b1401bc04d04fa3f90ca7018fc256afc67fc200390cbbL
e = 0x10001L
d = 0x17e6c54214a8dcdc7585ca8834aaf796a797496607aa7660153859d02ba399a5L
p = 0xd098978cde12b9e101b519d42ca54e7dL
q = 0xa8b69b77f593ca8a280dcd7d757d9597L
key_params = (n, e, d, p, q)
key = RSA.construct(key_params)
print key.exportKey()
```

And here's the output:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGpAgEAAiEAiXjunlKtXe4xOxQBvATQT6P5DKcBj8JWr8Z/wgA5DLsCAwEAAQIg
F+bFQhSo3Nx1hcqINKr3lqeXSWYHqnZgFThZ0CujmaUCEQDQmJeM3hK54QG1GdQs
pU59AhEAqLabd/WTyoooDc19dX2VlwIQeXiiqDGaDgxthhyoZedNsQIQOPeX3VSV
t7EYvzhgoXhrNwIQURb6TS79gHK6f+npSDFBPw==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 1):

A commonly used way to encode RSA keys is DER which derives semantic meaning via ASN.1. You can find more detail in [RFC3447](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447). The ASN.1 syntax for a DER-encoded string looks as follows:

```
  Version ::= INTEGER { two-prime(0), multi(1) }
      (CONSTRAINED BY
      {-- version must be multi if otherPrimeInfos present --})

  RSAPrivateKey ::= SEQUENCE {
      version           Version,
      modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
      publicExponent    INTEGER,  -- e
      privateExponent   INTEGER,  -- d
      prime1            INTEGER,  -- p
      prime2            INTEGER,  -- q
      exponent1         INTEGER,  -- d mod (p-1)
      exponent2         INTEGER,  -- d mod (q-1)
      coefficient       INTEGER,  -- (inverse of q) mod p
      otherPrimeInfos   OtherPrimeInfos OPTIONAL
  }
```

A sample private-key using the encoding and syntax above would look as follows:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGGAgEAAhkAr6M0MwwZb+PmNOex7pFe5IDLe+eKEhazAgMBAAECGBpkc9uX3dqq
bFVW224yqOR0m8LyV+x2wQINANs9bxnc7ZdljRmlHwINAM0WMid0p2sbmMOn7QIN
AMocs4yTOFFG5DJNHwIMOLmt76ndcMu2Sk/VAgwpTp5DBMk2FLZKfaY=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Final note: You've posted your private key online ... which means that you shouldn't use it anymore.